# Saving data to pList: `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' to 'NSMutableArray' error

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting the following error:

`Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x10dccdef0) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x10dccd978)`

I am using this tutorial: http://sweettutos.com/2015/06/03/swift-how-to-read-and-write-into-plist-files/
However, when I use the save function as:

```
func saveScore() {

    // Save note to plist
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let pathForThePlistFile = appDelegate.plistPathInDocument

    // Extract the content of the file as NSData

    let data:NSData =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsAtPath(pathForThePlistFile)!
    // Convert the NSData to mutable array

    do{
        let scoresArray = try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data, options: NSPropertyListMutabilityOptions.MutableContainersAndLeaves, format: nil) as! NSMutableArray

        scoresArray.addObject(self.totalScoreLabel.text!)

        // Save to plist
        scoresArray.writeToFile(pathForThePlistFile, atomically: true)

    }catch{

        print("An error occurred while writing to plist")
    }
```

The scoreArray is:
`var scoresArray:NSMutableArray!`

For the pList path, I am using this code in AppDelegate as instructed in the tutorial, thus creating a “scores.plist” file.

```
var plistPathInDocument:String = String()

func preparePlistForUse(){

    // 1
    let rootPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

    // 2
    plistPathInDocument = rootPath.stringByAppendingString("/scores.plist")
    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(plistPathInDocument){
        let plistPathInBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("scores", ofType: "plist") as String!

    // 3
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(plistPathInBundle, toPath: plistPathInDocument)
    }catch{
            print("Error occurred while copying file to document \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

I have made sure that the root of the scores.plist file is “Array”, not a dictionary.

I saw the same question here: [Swift. SIGABRT: cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' to 'NSMutableArray'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111323/swift-sigabrt-cast-value-of-type-nscfdictionary-to-nsmutablearray) but it was unanswered, please help.

Here's how my pList looks:

[image: plist screenshot]

Comment: The exception says that is a dictionary and not an array.  Can you show the start of your plist file?

Comment: @Paulw11, I added a screenshot

Comment: Is it possible that your copy isn't working and you are opening an older plist?  You should remove the forced downcast and set a breakpoint or print  `scoresArray` and see what it looks like

Comment: Go for a better tutorial if the tutorial really recommends to use `stringByAppendingString` to concatenate file path components. Also `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` is outdated and Apple recommends to use `URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:` of `NSFileManager`

Comment: Check out the source file for their tutorial, it's working properly.. I just wonder why it isn't working even when I downgraded the destination device to ios 8.3..

Comment: @vadian, may you refer me to a better tutorial?

Comment: No, but the tutorial should use contemporary API like `NSURL` rather than `String` for representing file paths and native Swift types like `[String]` rather than `NSMutableArray`